# Sublime Text - refresh Browser then get focus back?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, sublime-text-2

I work with a lot of CSS, requiring me to type in sublime text, refresh browser multiple times. To save time, I installed the Refresh Browser Extension (http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/sublime-text-refresh-browser/).. Works pretty well, but it makes the browser focus active so I can't keep typing on sublime unless I click on the screen or alt+tab.

Is there a way to get focus back to sublime after refreshing the browser? Either by editing the extension or with AHK, ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in sublime and have another browser window that's inactive, I'd suggest making a hotkey that uses [ControlSend](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm) to refresh the web page.

I would use ctrl+s as the hotkey. That way every time you save, it refreshes the page:

Try this:

```
~^s::ControlSend,, {F5}, ahk_exe firefox.exe
```

---

References:
[ControlSend](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm)